# Check entered phone number in app like whatsapp

Tags: ios, whatsapp

How I can check the phone number entered in the app is current phone number like whatsapp to verify phone number?

This option realized in whatsapp, when you login this moment verify process starts and check if your phone number from sim card is equal to entered phone number it is OK! If you use another phone number user with this another phone number gets sms with code to verify this phone number on your device.

Thanks!

Comment: please show us that you have at least attempted to solve the problem for yourself

Comment: iOS will not allow you to access to sim card phone number, nor are you able to get the phone number entered in the settings as the user phone number;

Comment: But it realized in whatsapp, so it's posible